# Parsing Json response from Httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, json, regex, json.net

I'm trying to parse data from a response using httpwebrequest, which is in JSON format, I've tried to use JSON.Net but seem to be having no luck, I'm open to using Regex if need be.

Example of current code -

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/response");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

dynamic data = JOBject.Parse(response);

Console.WriteLine(data.name);
```

Example of response in full -

```
[{"_id":"hello","_source":{"name":"hello","example":"hey"},"_type":"_doc"}]
```

Comment: Not a `JObject`, it's a `JArray`. Using dynamic: `dynamic data = JArray.Parse(response); Console.WriteLine(data[0]._source.name);`, without: `var data = JArray.Parse(response); Console.WriteLine(data[0]["_source"]["name"]);`. Deserializing to a class structure is something you could consider (unless the JSON returned is actually just like the one you're showing here).

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/response");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);

                Console.Write(data.name);
             }
```

Comment: That's identical to what I'm already doing, my references are just more compact but I will give it a go non the less :), thanks for your input & hopefully this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create these two classes like this.

```cs
public class Source
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("example")]
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseObject
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_source")]
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And then parse your response like this

```cs
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(response);
```

Hope this will help you